# WebClient DownloadString() counter?

Tags: c#

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 string url = "https://someurl.com/..."
 string get = client.DownloadString(url);
```

how can I count how many times `url` has been downloaded?

Comment: Count by counting? `download_counter += 1;`

Comment: Downloaded by your code? Or downloaded by anyone?

Comment: just use a normal variable , explain more to get help

Comment: @freedomn-m Downloaded by code.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to subclass the `WebClient` and override the method you want to take statistics on. I've chosen in the below implementation to keep statistics for any url that passes through `GetWebRequest`. I've extensively commented the code so I assume it is clear it boils down to keeping a count per `Uri`  in a dictionary.

```
// subclass WebClient
public class WebClientWithStats:WebClient
{
    // appdomain wide storage
    static Dictionary<Uri, long> stats = new Dictionary<Uri, long>();

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        // prevent multiple threads changing shared state
        lock(stats)
        {
            long count;
            // do we have thr Uri already, if yes, gets its current count
            if (stats.TryGetValue(request.RequestUri, out count))
            {
                // add one and update value in dictionary
                count++;
                stats[request.RequestUri] = count;
            }
            else
            {
                // create a new entry with value 1 in the dictionary
                stats.Add(request.RequestUri, 1);
            }
        }
        return base.GetWebResponse(request);
    }

    // make statistics available 
    public static Dictionary<Uri, long> Statistics
    {
        get
        {
            return new Dictionary<Uri, long>(stats);
        }
    }
}
```

A typical usage scenario looks like this:

```
using(var wc = new WebClientWithStats())
{
    wc.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com");
    wc.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com");
    wc.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com");
    wc.DownloadString("http://meta.stackoverflow.com");
    wc.DownloadString("http://stackexchange.com");
    wc.DownloadString("http://meta.stackexchange.com");
    wc.DownloadString("http://example.com");
}

var results = WebClientWithStats.Statistics;
foreach (var res in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is used {1} times", res.Key, res.Value);
}
```

Which will output:

> https://stackoverflow.com/ is used 3 times
> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ is used 1 times
> https://stackexchange.com/ is used 1 times
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/ is used 1 times
> http://example.com/ is used 1 times

I'll take the [pluralization bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236746/what-is-the-story-of-jeff-atwood-and-the-pluralization-bug) for granted.